# How to C - windows socket reading textfile content

Tags: winsock

I am having problems reading a text file content via winsock on C , does anyone have any idea how it should work? actually when I try to **GET HTTP** header from google am able to, but when I try on my **xampp** machine,

it just gives me 400 bad request.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

char *message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
```

Ok the problem that I was receiving 400 bad request on my localhost via winsock was the my HTTP request, i just changed the 1.1 to 1.0 .. and it worked!!! what I am wanting now is printing nothing the content of the text file and not the whole banner?! :)

Answer (score 0):

Read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), in particular sections 5.2 and 14.23. An HTTP 1.1 request is **required** to include a `Host` header, and an HTTP 1.1 server is **required** to send a 400 reply if the header is missing and no host is specified in the request line.

```
char *message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: hostnamehere\r\n\r\n";
```

As for the text content, you need to read from the socket until you encounter a `\r\n\r\n` sequence (which terminates the response headers), then process the headers, then read the text content accordingly.  The response headers tell you how to read the raw bytes of the text content and when to stop reading (refer to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) section 4.4 for details).  Once you have the raw bytes, the `Content-Type` header tells you how to interpret the raw bytes (data type, charset, etc).